# Using Jersey with Open Liberty in Gradle

Tags: jersey-2.0, open-liberty

I have a simple setup with gradle and Open Liberty. From this blogpost https://openliberty.io/blog/2018/12/14/microprofile21-18004.html
it says

"Open Liberty now has reactive extensions to JAX-RS 2.1 so that you can use providers from Apache CXF and Jersey"

But I can't get it to work with Jersey

I've tried various configurations of my build.gradle file and server.xml but still can't get it to work and find documentation lacking.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'liberty'
apply plugin: 'java-library'

group = 'x.y.z'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
description = "X Y Z"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}



buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.wasdev.wlp.gradle.plugins:liberty-gradle-plugin:2.6.3'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

//required for compiling, testing and running the application
dependencies {

    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '2.26'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-common', version: '2.26'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-server', version: '2.26'

    providedCompile group:'javax.servlet', name:'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.1.0'
    testCompile group:'commons-httpclient', name:'commons-httpclient', version:'3.1'
    testCompile group:'junit', name:'junit', version:'4.12'

    libertyRuntime group:'io.openliberty', name:'openliberty-runtime', version:'19.0.0.3'

    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

//Extra properties for project level 
ext {
    appName = project.name
    testServerHttpPort = 9080
    testServerHttpsPort = 9443
    warContext = appName
}

liberty {
    server {
        name = "${appName}Server"
        configFile = file("src/main/liberty/config/server.xml")
        bootstrapProperties = ['default.http.port': testServerHttpPort,
                               'default.https.port': testServerHttpsPort,
                               'app.context.root': warContext]
        packageLiberty {
            archive = "$buildDir/${appName}.zip"
            include = "usr"
        }
    }
}

war {
    archiveName = "${baseName}.${extension}"
}

//unit test configuration
test {
    reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/reports/unit")
    reports.junitXml.destination = file("$buildDir/test-results/unit")
    exclude '**/it/**'
}

//integration test configuration
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    group 'Verification'
    description 'Runs the integration tests.'
    reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/reports/it")
    reports.junitXml.destination = file("$buildDir/test-results/it")
    include '**/it/**'
    exclude '**/unit/**'

    systemProperties = ['liberty.test.port': testServerHttpPort, 'war.name': warContext]
}

task openBrowser {
    description = 'Open browser to http://localhost:8080/${warContext}'
    doLast {
        java.awt.Desktop.desktop.browse
            "http://localhost:${testServerHttpPort}/${appName}".toURI()
    }
}

task openTestReport {
    description = 'Open browser to the test report'
    doLast {
        java.awt.Desktop.desktop.browse file("$buildDir/reports/it/index.html").toURI()
    }
}

clean.dependsOn 'libertyStop'
check.dependsOn 'integrationTest'
integrationTest.dependsOn 'libertyStart'
integrationTest.finalizedBy 'libertyStop'
integrationTest.finalizedBy 'openTestReport'
libertyPackage.dependsOn 'libertyStop'
```

server.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">
    <featureManager>
        <!--   <feature>jsp-2.3</feature> -->
        <!--  <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature> -->
        <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
        <!--  
         -->
    </featureManager>
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="${default.http.port}"
                  httpsPort="${default.https.port}" />
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    <webApplication contextRoot="${app.context.root}" location="${app.context.root}.war" />
</server>
```

HelloWorldService

```java
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

}
```

When I try to hit the endpoint I get a 404

`curl localhost:9080/XYZ/hello/jersey`

Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /hello/jersey

Any help MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Do you have anywhere other class with `@ApplicationPath("/rest")`?

Comment: Hi @jimgug what is your end goal?  The article you mentioned talks about using reactive extensions (both Jersey and CXF have released extensions for RxJava and other reactive technologies), but it looks like you are trying to use the Jersey JAX-RS implementation in OpenLiberty (rather than a Jersey reactive extension provider).  If you want to use Jersey as the JAX-RS impl, then I recommend pulling in the JAX-RS APIs in addition to the Jersey libraries you already use.  You may need to add a web.xml to the app to use a Jersey servlet (not sure, sorry).

Comment: If you want to use a Jersey-made reactive provider, then I recommend using this blog post and it's sample code as a guide: https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/04/10/jaxrs-reactive-extensions.html
  The sample uses CXF's RxJava provider, but you would just need to swap providers. Hope this helps!